# Grails2.4x and spring-security-core:2.0-RC4: cannt use Requestmap

Tags: grails, spring-security

Grails2.4.3 , spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 and hibernate4:4.3.6.1(or hibernate4:4.3.5.5):
Config.groovy

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.myapp.secure.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.myapp.secure.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.myapp.secure.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'org.myapp.secure.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
```

when I run the app I get a blank page stating that this page has a redirect loop

I found the following error in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ReflectionUtils

```
static List loadAllRequestmaps() {
    getRequestMapClass().list()

}
```

Method on class [org.myapp.secure.Requestmap] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported [as a bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-312). There are workarounds described in the bug report. If you disable forking (individually, or by commenting out the whole `grails.project.fork` block) it should work. Also you should upgrade to 2.4.4 - there is a significant plugin-related issue fixed that affects classpath ordering between the application and plugins that might be contributing to this.